# Searching for data in SQLite DB table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a text view in which user enters a string. I need to search for that string in a table and return a boolean value if a string matches.

I am not into SQL, so can anyone please help me figure out how to do it.

Comment: Some details about the table's schema and what environment you're working in (Android, iOS, ...) would help.

Comment: Can you specify what mu is too short saying..we need the details to help you.

Comment: I m looking for Android dev. There is a table called employeeinfo and i need to just get the info whether the entered empid is already present in empId column or not

Comment: I have updated my answer, hopefully it is now exactly covering your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you know the basics & the object db of type SQLiteDatabase exists in your DataAccessLayer, below is the function which returns true false based on whether the location exists or not?

```
public boolean IsRecordExists(long empid) throws SQLException
{
     String where = "empid =" + empid;
     Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "employeeinfo", new String[] {"empid"}, where, null,null, null, null, null);

      if (mCursor != null) 
      {
           if(mCursor.moveToFirst())
                return true;
          else
                return false;
       }
    return false;
}
```